# How can I change the text of Label reading from a local resource file? in Javascript or jQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, file, resources

I have a label control which text has to be changed dynamically based on date selected by the user. But the text has to come from Local Resource file.
 I have to change the text on client side..so I am using the Javascript/JQuery.
Can you please help me reading the text from resource file in Javascript/JQuery.

I am using the AJAX Calendar Extender for the date selection and I am changing the text on OnClientDateSelectionChanged event, So I have to do it on the client side..please help me...
Thanks and appreciate your feedback.

Comment: sure..can you please tell me how to select the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no direct support for reading resources from the client side.

Here is a blog post that has a solution for [serving resources to JavaScript from ASP.NET](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Apr/02/A-Localization-Handler-to-serve-ASPNET-Resources-to-JavaScript).

As to posting your date selection back to the server, this seems like it could easily be handled by an AJAX call which jQuery has excellent support for.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your reply Paul. But I do not need to postback it to the server..I need to handle it on the client side..So Can you pleaase provide is there any way to read the resource at client side.